# Error occurs when Xtext Grammars Extending Other Xtext Grammar

Tags: xtext

I have two Eclipse plugin Xtext(2.11) projects.(Called Project A and B)  Project B grammar file is dependent on Project A grammar file.

I faced the problem in generating the jar (application plugin) from Gradle when I extend B's grammar from the file A

Project B: grammar file: when I used below lines:

```
grammar B with A
```

it gives me below error, whilge generating the gradle build target:

> 815  [main] ERROR mf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher  - **Problems running workflow B: Problem parsing** 'file:/C:/Users/cpra/workspaceDSLNew1__final/B.parent/B/../B/src/com/apama/studio/query/ext/B.xtext':
>   XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:2 **Couldn't resolve reference to Grammar 'A**'.

I have followed below steps:

1. Created Xtext Project A, edited grammar and generated artifacts.
2. Created Xtext Project B
3. Added project A's dependencies in MANIFEST.MF of project B.
4. Edited grammar file for extending another grammar file.

Faced with above error, kindly let me know if I missed anything?

> I can see one bug related to this
>   https://github.com/plugbee/dslforge/issues/19, is this valid for Xtext 2.11 LSP generation also?

Comment: How does you update to eclipse / gradle / maven (whatever you use ) dependencies look like?

Comment: Can you share a complete hello world project

Comment: I have added my source at https://github.com/chetanladdha/sample/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are different things todo

make sure the MyDslA.xtext is actually packaged
https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/issues/284
a.parent/gradle/source-layout.gradle

```
sourceSets.all {
    //resources.exclude '**/*.g', '**/*.xtext', '**/*.mwe2', '**/*.xtend', '**/*._trace'
    // remove xtext from the exclusion
    resources.exclude '**/*.g', '**/*.mwe2', '**/*.xtend', '**/*._trace'
}
```

add mavenLocal to b
b.parent/build.gradle

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }
    // this line is new
    mavenLocal()
}
```

add dep from b to a
b.parent/b/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext:${xtextVersion}"
    compile "org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext.xbase:${xtextVersion}"
    // this line is new
    compile "a:a:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

remove the standalonesetup crap from 
b.parent/b/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDslB.mwe2